# Cannot close a running event loop discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've migrating my discord bot to use MySQL instead of storing data in json files. The only problem I got now is when I try to load the music extension of the bot...
Code:

```
import discord
import lavalink
from discord import Guild
from discord import User
from discord.ext import commands

# from bot import get_musicchannel
# from bot import get_prefix
from bot import mycursor


def get_musicchannel(guild: Guild):
    # with open("cogs/music.json") as f:
    #     channels = json.load(f)
    # channel: TextChannel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, id=channels[str(guild.id)])
    # return channel.id
    sqlcommand = "SELECT channelid FROM musicchannels WHERE guildid = %s"
    vals = (guild.id,)
    mycursor.execute(sqlcommand, vals)
    result = mycursor.fetchall()
    strchannelid = str(result[0]).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(",", "")
    channelid = int(strchannelid)
    return channelid


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.music = lavalink.Client(self.bot.user.id)
        self.bot.music.add_node("IP", 2333, 'PASS', 'eu', 'music-node')
        self.bot.add_listener(self.bot.music.voice_update_handler, 'on_socket_response')
        self.bot.music.add_event_hook(self.track_hook)

    @commands.command(name="music")
    async def music(self, ctx, opt, *, arg=None):
        if ctx.message.channel.id != get_musicchannel(ctx.guild):
            # channel = get_musicchannel(ctx.guild)
            actual_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, id=get_musicchannel(ctx.guild))
            return await ctx.send(f"Music commands can only be used in the music channel ({actual_channel.mention})")
        if opt == "join":
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.members)
            if member is not None and member.voice is not None:
                vc = member.voice.channel
                player = self.bot.music.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id, endpoint=str(ctx.guild.region))
                if not player.is_connected:
                    player.store('channel', ctx.guild.id)
                    await self.connect_to(ctx.guild.id, str(vc.id))
        # Unimportant code

    async def track_hook(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, lavalink.events.QueueEndEvent):
            guild_id = int(event.player.guild_id)
            await self.connect_to(guild_id, None)

    async def connect_to(self, guild_id: int, channel_id: int):
        ws = self.bot._connection._get_websocket(guild_id)
        await ws.voice_state(str(guild_id), channel_id)

    async def disconnect_from(self, guild_id: int):
        ws = self.bot._connection.voice_clients
        print(ws)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

When I try to run the bot it gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 668, in run
    loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 314, in run_forever
    assert self._self_reading_future is None
AssertionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 93, in _cleanup_loop
    _cancel_tasks(loop)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 78, in _cancel_tasks
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True))
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 592, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 552, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 607, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Ficheiros\Pastas\Tudo\Coding\Python\Projects\Server-Utils\cogs\music.py", line 11, in <module>
    from bot import mycursor
  File "D:\Ficheiros\Pastas\Tudo\Coding\Python\Projects\Server-Utils\bot.py", line 1383, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 674, in run
    _cleanup_loop(loop)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 98, in _cleanup_loop
    loop.close()
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 674, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Ficheiros/Pastas/Tudo/Coding/Python/Projects/Server-Utils/bot.py", line 421, in on_ready
    bot.load_extension('cogs.music')
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 664, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 610, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.music' raised an error: RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The on_ready event just has `bot.load_extension('cogs.music')` that's where the error comes from
I don't know what can I do to make this run... Help is appreciated.